# Facebook application unavailable for some users

Tags: facebook

I'm having a weird problem in my Facebook apps. It shows a "Application is unavailable" error but only for some users (actually, for the most part). I'm the only administrator of the page and I assume I can see it working for that reason. However, two of my friends who are testing can see it and everyone else can't.

I used Facebook's Debug Tool to check if anything was wrong but it seems to be ok.

The app page is: http://apps.facebook.com/taggeoapp/

Thanks in advance for any hint... I really don't know what is going on...

Comment: My appID is 200262963434269

Comment: Weird. I'd recommend filing a bug @ developers.facebook.com/bug